# TypeError: res.json is not a function. Having trouble sending back information to the front end using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am building an application that needs a currency converter API. I am having trouble with returning the data to the front end. (My console.log is showing the desired data to be returned, however I keep getting TypeError: res.json is not a function)

Please see the code below

```js
App.post('/rates', async (res) => {
  console.log('route was hit')

  const response = await axios.get(`https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/${process.env.API_KEY}/latest/CAD`)
  
  console.log(response)

  res.json(response)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback of post takes two arguments, first is `request` and second one is  `response`. Your code should look like:

```
App.post('/rates', async (request, res) => {...
```